# Google Play console loging and password for robot testing

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I have an app that requires login and password at the main activity.

As I can see the test performed by google robots is limited to only parts that are not login required.
Is there a way that I can add login credentials to google console to perform full testing?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the [official article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757) it is possible to [provide the credentials of the test account](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757?hl=en&visit_id=637606609137238839-1819296483&rd=1#zippy=%2Cturn-off-pre-launch-reports%2Cset-up-credentials)

> Step 1: Provide test account credentials if your app has a sign-in screen
> If your app has a sign-in screen and you want the crawler to test the sign-in process or the content behind it, you need to provide account credentials. Note that you do not need to provide credentials if your app supports "Sign-in with Google,” which enables the crawler to log in automatically.

> Open Play Console.
> Select an app.
> On the left menu, select Testing > Pre-launch report > Settings.
> In the “Test account credentials” section, select Provide credentials.
> Enter the following:
> Username: The username associated with your test account.
> Password: The password associated with your test account.
> Click Save. These credentials will be used for all future tests unless edited.

Comment: there are also two fields for identifiers. are they just E-mail and Password? or its more on a code level?